# Socket server and socket client java - detecting server from client located on different computers

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, detection, hostname

So currently i am connecting to the server side via IP address, but i want it to not having the need to specify IP-address of the server computer. Anyhow i can just detect that a current serversocket is open on the network and connect to that from the clientside?

This is what i write for the server:

```
server = new ServerSocket(1234,100);
```

and on the client side:

```
connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("someIpAddress"),1234);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server is always on the same network, you can always use UDP broadcasting to detect a service.

The server listens for the broadcasts, and then replies thereby sending its IP address.

If the server and client are on different networks, with at lease one router in between, then there is no way to "detect" the server from the client.

Comment: OP is specifically concerned about java(please check that tag). I don't think this approach would directly help him as he'd have to use 3rd party tools to achieve what you have added as an answer.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I'm not that familiar with Java, but are you telling me that there is no way to create an UDP socket in Java? Or to set the `SO_BROADCAST` socket flag?

Comment: I am more concerned about the last paragraph of your answer(the reason being routers and gateways generally don't forward broadcast messages). I am not saying that it is not possible; but, unlike C, one may need to use external libraries for achieving the last section.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Oh that's not possible in C or any other language either. It's just how most routers are set up, to not forward broadcast packets.

Comment: I agree, that's why i hinted that OP may need to use 3rd party libraries/tools to achieve the same, in my answer.

Comment: No external library is needed for Broadcasting detection. You just open up a DatagramSocket and send packets to broadcast (255.255.255.255). Other clients will do the same and listen for packets from broadcast. Once they recieve a reply you will be able to figure out their IP address based on the DatagramPacket.

Answer (score 1):

> i want it to not having the need to specify IP-address of the server
> computer. Anyhow i can just detect that a current serversocket is open
> on the network and connect to that from the clientside?

Two aspects are discussed below :

1. If you don't know about the server in the given network, then detecting that a server socket is running on a known port is a very cumbersome task. The Java SE doesn't have the strength to *automatically* determine which system(in the network) has a server socket listening on X port. You'd need 3rd party tools for achieving the same. You can have a hit-and-trial based approach to determine that.
2. Another point, if you know the hostname of the server(like "someIpAddress.com" in your code), then in that case, it all boils down to a hostname-resolver which would get the IP-address from the passed hostname.

   You can have a mapping in the /etc/hosts file of the client about the server hostname and IP. Or, alternatively you can have a DNS server which would redirect your request to the IP, and let you connect to the server listening on the X port.